# PC-LINT error 5448: token is not a valid binary operator in a preprocessor subexpression

Tags: c-preprocessor, pc-lint, rl78

today I wanna try analyze my source code via PC-LINT.
I configured PC lint for my compiler - RL78. And it seems like it works.

Meanwhile I added more files to analyze, and then I noticed one strange error.
`error: 5448: token is not a valid binary operator in a preprocessor subexpression`

Problem was found in #if condition:

```
#define Uart0_DivideWithRounding(A, B)  ((TLong)( (A) / (B) + 0.5 ))
#define Uart0_CalculateDivisionRatio(lfsInputFrequency, lBaudRate)  Uart0_DivideWithRounding((lfsInputFrequency)/2.0, lBaudRate)
#define dlUart0_CalculatedDivisionRatio0     Uart0_CalculateDivisionRatio(dfsUart0_InputFrequency0,dUart0_BaudRate)

#if dlUart0_CalculatedDivisionRatio0 > dUart0_DivisionRatioLimitHigh
```

I realized I have there casting and div of floating numbers.
My compiler can handle that somehow... (IAR1.40.6 RL78)

Problem is that, I can't change anything in my source code,
cuz this code is a part of company internal library.

Any suggestion how I can deal with it?

I tried to suppressed this error, but its not a solution.
Pc lint cant process it, and go into #if condition and then to #error.
Then pc-lint abort execution.

I tried to fined answer in compiler documentation, but without success.

Comment: Typical solutions revert to #defines before going to this code, patching the expression. But that neither nice, nor easy. Here I have no idea,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution of my problem.
This problematic makro can be overwriten in Pc-lint config file.
In that way:

```
++ddlUart0_CalculatedDivisionRatio0=52
```